# Java Servlet - Parameter name and value not received from request object

Tags: java

I am using tomcat 9.0.13. Calling the below ajax request from a jsp file, when i use `request.getParameter("work")` the value returned is empty.

But i am able to get value for `request.getParameter("query")` which also has `%` in the value.

If i remove `%` in the value of work Parameter, in this case, `request.getparamter` is returning the correct value.

Any suggestions to solve this issue?

```
    Ext.Ajax.request({
    url :'/final/servlet/com.xx.testservlet?work=testing%',
    scope:this,
    method: 'POST',
    params: {
            query: 'queryss%',
            },

    success: function(response)
    {
       var jsonText = response.responseText;
       alert(jsonText)
   },
   failure:function()
   {
     alert('failure')
   }
     });
```

Comment: `%` is special sign in URL used at [percent encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). If you want to pass it as symbol encode it using `%25` (use it instead of `%`).